# How to display max and min values on a SeekBar?

Tags: android, user-interface, seekbar

What I'm trying to do:

1. I would like to implement a `SeekBar` in an Android App and on that `SeekBar` I would also like to display the max and min values. Min value would always be 0 but max value is dependent on clip length. (Example: 0---180)
2. Is there a way to display the value (on the seek bar itself) that is selected when the user moves the `SeekBar`?

I am not being able to figure out, how to implement this along with the android `SeekBar`, as there doesn't seem to be any option available for displaying values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would like to implement a seekbar in an Android App. But on the
> seekbar I would also like to display the max and min values. Min value
> would always be 0 but max value is dependent on clip length. (Example:
> 0---180)
>
> Is there a way to display the value (on the seek bar itself) that is selected when the user > moves the seekbar?

If you want those values **on top** of the `SeekBar` then extend the `SeekBar` class and override the `onDraw` method. After calling `super.onDraw(canvas)` you can then draw your own stuff, like the min/max values at the start and end of the `SeekBar` or the current progress. Making something that looks good(on all the different looking `Seekbars` out there) will be something a bit harder as you'll need to carefully calculate where and how you draw the text.

A simpler approach would be to make a custom component wrapping the `SeekBar` with a `TextView` on it's left and right(with an optional `TextView` below for the current progress) and set those with the min/max values(even if the max values is set programmatically, the max `TextView` could be made to "follow" those changes). The progress can be easily calculated and updated knowing the width of the `SeekBar` and the current progress.

A small example for the second case:

```
public static class SeekBarWithValues extends RelativeLayout {

    private int mMax = 100;
    private TextView mMinText;
    private TextView mMaxText;
    private TextView mCurrentText;
    private SeekBar mSeek;

    public SeekBarWithValues(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.content, this);
        // the minimum value is always 0
        mMinText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.minValue);
        mMinText.setText("0");
        mMaxText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.maxValue);
        mCurrentText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.curentValue);
        mSeek = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        mSeek.setMax(100);
        mMaxText.setText(String.valueOf(mSeek.getMax()));
    }

    /**
     * This needs additional work to make the current progress text stay
     * right under the thumb drawable.
     * 
     * @param newProgress
     *            the new progress for which to place the text
     */
    public void updateCurrentText(int newProgress) {
        mCurrentText.setText(String.valueOf(newProgress));
        final int padding = mMinText.getWidth() + mSeek.getPaddingLeft();
        final int totalSeekWidth = mSeek.getWidth();
        final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) mCurrentText
                .getLayoutParams();
        final int seekLocation = (mSeek.getProgress() * totalSeekWidth)
                / mMax - mCurrentText.getWidth() / 2;
        lp.leftMargin = seekLocation + padding;
        mCurrentText.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }

    public SeekBar getSeekBar() {
        return mSeek;
    }

    public void updateSeekMaxValue(int newValue) {
        mMax = newValue;
        mMaxText.setText(mMax);
        mSeek.setMax(mMax);
    }

}
```

Where the content layout is:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/minValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/seekBar"
    android:gravity="center" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/maxValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/seekBar"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/seekBar"
    android:gravity="center" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@id/seekBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/maxValue"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/minValue" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/curentValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/seekBar"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

The current text tends to be offseted more than it should and additional work is required to put it right under the seek handle.

Comment: thank you very much. could you please provide a sample for using the testview on the left and right of the seekbar dialog

Comment: @Sunny See my edited answer, keep in mind that is something very basic.

Comment: I'd like to add that if you want it to be between max and min, you need to do `final int seekLocation = (((newProgress-mMin) * totalSeekWidth) / (mMax-mMin)) - (mCurrentText.getWidth());`