# SeekBar with numbered heading

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

How can I create a seekbar that has numbers above it. For example if the SeekBar has Max=10, it will have 0 to 10 above the seekbar.

I tried to do this by creating a custom view that sits above the Seekbar, this view extends linear layout(horizontal), n number textviews (n = seekbar max attribute) are added to the LinearLayout. The problem is that I couldnt get the numbers to sit directly above the 'notches' on the seekbar.

Am I approaching this in the correct way or should I be creating a customview that extends Seekbar and adding the numbers by drawing them onto a canvas? Could someone please give me a few pointers on how this problem can be solved.

Here is the code I have so far, the prpblem is, as stated above, no matter how I try to play around with the padding on both seekbar and my custom view, I cannot get the numbers to align perfectly with the seekbar notches(selected index)

```
   public class SeekBarNumberIndicator extends LinearLayout
     {

 TextView[] mNumbers;


    public SeekBarNumberIndicator(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public SeekBarNumberIndicator(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {

        super(context, attrs);
        initView(context, attrs);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public SeekBarNumberIndicator(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        initView(context, attrs);
    }

    protected void initView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        mNumbers = new TextView[11];
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);

        for(int x = 0; x < 11; x++){
            mNumbers[x] = new TextView(context);
            mNumbers[x].setLayoutParams(lp);
            mNumbers[x].setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            mNumbers[x].setText(String.valueOf(x));
            mNumbers[x].setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            //mNumbers[x].setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);

            super.addView(mNumbers[x]);

        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I tried the link you posted, the same problem occurs, the sliding text view doesnt appear directly under the thumb, the offset gradually increases. What extra measures could I take to make the textview appear directly under the thumb(if I can solve this then Im sure the solution can be adapted to suite the custom view in my OP). I know I can start adding some logic to the padding that increases by some exponential value but this seems 'hacky' thanks

Comment: Add your tried code here..

Comment: Thanks, added code of my custom view

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383623/how-to-display-max-and-min-values-on-a-seekbar