# Default Max and Min Values don't show up unless the range seekbar handlers are moved

Tags: java, android, android-seekbar

Is there any way to make the default max and min values to show up without having to move the range seekbar handlers?

[image]

As you can see, the min and max values are missing at start.

I couldn't find any rangeSeekBar methods that set the min and max values other than `setSelectedMaxValue`,`setSelectedMinValue`.

Example Code

```
public class SeekbarDoubleDialog extends DialogFragmentAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Context context = getActivity();
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        final String maxString = bundle.getString("data");
        Double maxNumber = Double.parseDouble(maxString);
        final RangeSeekBar<Double> rangeSeekBar = new RangeSeekBar<Double>(context);
        rangeSeekBar.setSelectedMinValue(0.00);
        rangeSeekBar.setSelectedMaxValue(maxNumber);
        rangeSeekBar.setRangeValues(0.00, maxNumber * 2);
        rangeSeekBar.setTextAboveThumbsColor(R.color.color_primary);
        FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.range_seekbar_ph);
        layout.addView(rangeSeekBar);

    }

}
```

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15384470/1727937) will help you

Answer (score 0):

Just put in xml this line :

```
app:activateOnDefaultValues="true"
```

it will always show the value above the thumbs.